# How to validate or get the value from the Input parameter of (Type Table) in Stored procedure in Oracle PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, object, stored-procedures, input, types

I need to check the value in the Input parameter whether it is NULL or NOT in Stored procedure. The Input Parameter is of Table type and contains nested object in it. It contains 3 attributes - employee id, manager_id and address. I need to check if the manager_id and employee_id is NULL or not.Based on the values if it is NULL, i need to insert into two different tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY order_mgr 
IS

PROCEDURE ins_trees (  p_emp_details_in    IN  trees_type_t,  
                       p_nrmployee_Id      IN  NUMBER                                     
                     )
BEGIN

      -- Condition goes here.. please let me know how to check this in the table type object as it contains nested object.
    -- IF the manager_id is NULL in the trees_type_t type object 
           THEN

          INSERT into emp (employee_id, address)
          values(p_emp_details_in.employee_id, p_emp_details_in.address_id);
           END IF;

       -- Condition goes here.. please let me know how to check this in the table type object as it contains nested object.
    -- IF the (employee_id  is NULL in the trees_type_t type object then

          INSERT into manager (manager_id, address)
          values(p_emp_details_in.manager_id,p_emp_details_in.address_id);
    END IF;

END;

END;
/
```

Object type:

```
create or replace TYPE trees_type_t  AS TABLE OF tree_obj_type;
```

```
create or replace TYPE   tree_obj_type AS OBJECT 
   (
    employee_id VARCHAR2(10), 
    manager_id  VARCHAR2(10), 
    address  VARCHAR2(100), 
  );
```

Please suggest and help me.

Comment: Your code will not work. p_emp_details_in   is a collection.  You have to iterate over it to get each object value.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume that since you're accepting a collection, your intention is to iterate over each element in the collection.  Your code doesn't have a loop which I assume you intended to have.  Second, I assume that the collection is dense (i.e. there are no indexes that are unpopulated)

You likely want something like

```
FOR i IN 1 .. p_emp_details_in.count 
LOOP
  IF p_emp_details_in(i).employee_id IS NOT NULL
  THEN 
    INSERT into emp (employee_id, address)
      values(p_emp_details_in(i).employee_id, p_emp_details_in(i).address_id);
  END IF;

  IF p_emp_details_in(i).manager_id IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    INSERT into manager (manager_id, address)
      values(p_emp_details_in(i).manager_id,p_emp_details_in(i).address_id);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Of course, if you don't need to use PL/SQL, you could do this with a single `INSERT ALL`

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN employee_id IS NOT NULL
    INTO emp(employee_id, address) VALUES( employee_id, address )
  WHEN manager_id IS NOT NULL
    INTO manager( manager_id, address ) VALUES( manager_id, address )
SELECT employee_id, manager_id, address
  FROM TABLE( p_emp_details_in );
```